# Point inside Polygon check

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

I have written a method to determine whether a Vector2 lies inside a polygon or outside of it. The polygon is defined by an array of clockwise vertices, p[]. It returns true if the point is inside, false otherwise.

```
public bool polyCheck(Vector2 v, Vector2[] p)
{
    int j = p.Length-1;
    bool c = false;
    for(int i=0;i<p.Length;j=i++)c^=p[i].y>v.y^p[j].y>v.y&&v.x<(p[j].x-p[i].x)*(v.y-p[i].y)/(p[j].y-p[i].y)+p[i].x;
    return c;
}
```

It is perfectly functional, works with all edge cases, and is blazing fast. I want to know how I could make the method look prettier, and have better 'coding practices' though.

Comment: Removing all white space doesn't make code faster.

Comment: Almost a code golf.

Comment: Purely FYI, here's a popular one:  http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=PolyContainsPoint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Naming (signature): polyCheck is not a clear name. And the arguments's names could help explain the function's semantic as well.

  ```
  public bool IsPointInPolygon(Vector2 point, Vector2[] polygon)
  ```
- Packing / golfing: not using the `{}` for the `for` loop doesn't help for anything (including speed), neither does packing all the computation in one line : it just makes the code impossible to read which seems of little use. In the same manner, make the operator precedence obvious by using `()` and using several lines.
- Performance:

  1. What is striking at first glance is the redundancy of `p[i]` and `p[j]`: do cache those vectors inside some vars. 8 array indirection per polygon point can be avoided. And even better : cache the polygon point's coordinates instead of caching the polygon points to save 6 property indirection per polygon point.
  2. point.x and point.y won't change: cache them.
  3. after reading more closely, since `i` always follows `j`, you could load `p[j]` from `p[i]`, or rather those points' coordinates, to reduce by a factor of 2 the array/property access.
  4. Maybe you are doing this test before, but computing a bounding box for your polygons and using it as a first test could -depending on many factors of course- tremendously speed up things.
- Naming (variables): c, p, ... think about someone else reading this code... or you in 3 months !!!

I'd be curious to know if this code is faster, and by which amount, since compilers are very smart. Let me know if you happen to test it!

```
public bool IsPointInPolygon(Vector2 point, Vector2[] polygon) {
   int polygonLength = polygon.Length, i=0;
   bool inside = false;
   // x, y for tested point.
   float pointX = point.x, pointY = point.y;
   // start / end point for the current polygon segment.
   float startX, startY, endX, endY;
   Vector2 endPoint = polygon[polygonLength-1];           
   endX = endPoint.x; 
   endY = endPoint.y;
   while (i<polygonLength) {
      startX = endX;           startY = endY;
      endPoint = polygon[i++];
      endX = endPoint.x;       endY = endPoint.y;
      //
      inside ^= ( endY > pointY ^ startY > pointY ) /* ? pointY inside [startY;endY] segment ? */
                && /* if so, test if it is under the segment */
                ( (pointX - endX) < (pointY - endY) * (startX - endX) / (startY - endY) ) ;
   }
   return inside;
}
```

Comment: I made a few edits to further improve performance that are only possible now because I can read the code more easily!

Comment: Oddly enough, your method with the caching and my improvements, takes 50% more time than my original method without a single improvement! This needs more testing. (results of 10000 random point tests on a random polygon with 20 points: polyCheck:25460ns, IsPointInPolygon:37700ns)

Comment: Undid the reordering of the expression after I noticed extraneous results, turns out that I would need to flip the inequality if (startY - endY) is negative since I am multiplying by a negative. I did some further investigation, and it seems that the caching itself is slowing it down.

Comment: A bit surprising... Compilers are sometimes smarter than us, i wonder if we can beat it here. Maybe it's unrolling the loop. ??? Vector seems of type double, i also wonder if there's a type conversion/check when loading them into a float var...

Comment: Vector2 is from the Unity engine, it is most certainly of float precision, at least according to the documentation, and Mono. I think the performance degradation has something to do with the reusing of the variables, I'm going to try moving the variable declarations into the for loop. I think that it's causing the CPU to reuse registers and maybe one-use registers are faster. (But this is absolutely pure speculation on my part, I would need to disassemble it and I am not sure how to go about doing that, or what to do once it is disassembled).

Comment: Could it be that the compiler optimizes the for loop better than the while? Also I wonder if there's a clean way to avoid that FP div there. I know I can multiply both sides by the absolute value of (startY - endY), leaving a multiplication of signum(startY - endY) on the right side, but that is potentially slower because I am not sure if absolute value and signum branch or not. (Branches are waaay slower than FP div).

Comment: You can look at the byte-code generated quite easily with some tools (search 'C# spy code'). For and while should both be very well treated i guess. Yes, trading a div for a mul might be worth a try... and to be fair you should do the same in your original code... Damn it ! those compilers are smart !!! :-)

Answer (score 11):

> I want to know how I could make the method look prettier, and have better 'coding practices' though

- avoid single letter variable if they aren't iterator variables. If you or **Sam the maintainer** needs to come back to this method in a few months, neither you nor **Sam** will grasp at first glance what the variables are about.
- avoid shortening of method names. `polyCheck` does not tell anything about what the method tries to do. A name like `IsInPolygon` would be better. With a more OO approach by adding a `Polygon` class having a method `Contains(Vector2)` it would be more clear.

  ```
  public class Polygon
  {
      public Vector2[] Vertices { get; private set; }
      public Polygon(Vector2[] vertices)
      {
          Vertices = vertices;
      }
      public bool ContainsVector(Vector2 vector)
      {
          // do the magic
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- always use braces `{}` although they are optional for single lined `for`'s. This will help you to make your code less error prone.
- let your variables and operators have some space to breathe. This

  ```
  c^=p[i].y>v.y^p[j].y>v.y&&v.x<(p[j].x-p[i].x)*(v.y-p[i].y)/(p[j].y-p[i].y)+p[i].x;
  ```

  is just not readable.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do those things. Should I put the result in an edit to the question?

Comment: Nope. Adding updated code isn't allowed on code review if the question has answers because it would invalidate these answers.

Comment: Also, use temporary variables to hold intermediate values.  The compiler will optimize them away in many cases, and having them in the code will make what you're doing much clearer.